# How to save header request using REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django 3.0.7 and Django Rest Framework

my `models.py` looks like this:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
        title                           = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
        body                            = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
        header                          = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
        image                           = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=False, blank=False)
        date_published          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="date published")
        date_updated            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="date updated")
        author                          = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        slug                            = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

        def __str__(self):
                return self.title
```

`serializers.py`:

```
class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'image', 'date_updated', 'username']
```

`views.py`:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def api_create_blog_view(request):

    blog_post = BlogPost(author=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = BlogPostSerializer(blog_post, data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I need to save header in "header" database field, i tried to save somehow like this:

`serializer = BlogPostSerializer(blog_post, data=request.data, header=request.META)`

but it's didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is on the right track. 
`HttpRequest.META` gives a dictionary containing all available HTTP headers. You could also use `HttpRequest.headers`, it is a simpler way to access all HTTP-prefixed headers, plus CONTENT_LENGTH and CONTENT_TYPE.

You could save the value after the `is_valid()` check.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def api_create_blog_view(request):

    blog_post = BlogPost(author=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = BlogPostSerializer(blog_post, data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(header=request.headers)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```